# WSO2APIM - Application visible to all admins

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using WSO2AM 2.1.0 we have a question.

By default the applications of the store are created by subscriber and each subscriber can see only own application (what makes sense).

However here we have an environment where admins want to create a clientapplication configuration and then just pass client credentials to the clients (or developers). In this case - is it possible for admins could see/access applications of other admins?

Edit: I thought I could see applications of other users in the carbon console logged in as an administrator (under service providers). but apparently I see only mine .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled the application sharing feature?

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Sharing+Applications+Between+Multiple+Groups

Comment: Seems this parameter is as well available in APIM 2.1.0 I will check.. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I've enabled the `GroupingExtractor`, assigned an organization claim, but the Store doesn't show any field to define the organization.. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Are you using a wum updated pack?
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Sharing+Applications+Between+Multiple+Groups

This feature is available for GA from APIM 2.2.0. Else you will have to use a update-12 pack from git.
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v2.1.0-update12

Comment: The client claims they have wso2 subscription, so hopefully their docker images are up-to-date :)

Comment: don't you accidentally know how to "wum-update" the apim-kubernetes images?

Comment: The apim docker images are wum updated and pushed weekly to wso2 docker regisrty. If you have a valid subscription you should be able to pull the images from http://docker.wso2.com/.

Else, you will have to build the docker image from wum updated wso2am pack.
https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/base/apim/Dockerfile