# WUM update of api-kubernetes image

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have a requirement to use application grouping in the API store ( [see my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793611/wso2apim-application-visible-to-all-admins) - with wso2 apim 2.1.0).  The client uses apim-kubernetes  and they claim they have an active wso2 subscrption (wum).

Question - do I need to rebuild the docker images with the newest product updates or is there a way to get already "wummed" images as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WUM updated docker images are pushed to the wso2 docker registry, every week. If you have a valid subscription you should be able to pull the docker images with wum updated product distribution.
http://docker.wso2.com/

If there is an urgent fix (that cannot wait for a week), you can do the wum update and build the docker image manually. 
https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/base/apim/Dockerfile